# How to insert text with "< >" characters into TinyMCE as plain text, without it being considered a HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, tinymce

In my project, I have used a TinyMCE text editor. I also have a button that, when clicked, my javascript code will copy the value from the button into the text editor.

**For example** : If the button value is `[first_name]`, clicking the button will put the text `[first_name]` (short code format in wordpress) into the text editor.

That works, but now I have changed my button value from `[first_name]` to `<<first_name>>`. When I click the button it should put `<<first_name>>` into the text editor, but it is only putting `<>`. It is not putting the full value because the text editor considers `<<first_name>>` as a HTML tag.

Also, I have tried with HTML entities such as `&lt;` and `&gt;` but it doesn't work either.

**Note:** it should not be a source code editor. It must be a simple text editor.

Can anyone please guide me on how to solve this problem?

**My HTML Code:**

**Button Part -**

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
<a class="btn btn-primary sInput_netadvimage" href="<<first_name>>" style="width: 100%">FIRST NAME</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
<a class="btn btn-primary sInput_netadvimage" href="<<company_name>>" style="width: 100%">COMPANY NAME</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Text Editor Part**

```
<textarea name="content[]" id="tedit-1" class="tmeditor contentfield" name="area"></textarea>
```

**Jquery Part**

```
$(document.body).on('blur', '.contentfield', function() {
    currentreplaceelement = $(this);
});

$(document.body).on('click', ".sInput_netadvimage", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var code = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(code);
    if (currentreplaceelement != '') {
        if (currentreplaceelement.hasClass('subjectfield')) {
            var a = currentreplaceelement.val();
            var output = [a.slice(0, currentreplaceposition), code, a.slice(currentreplaceposition)].join('');
            currentreplaceelement.val(output);
            //  currentreplaceelement = '';
            //   currentreplaceposition = '';
        } else {
            tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, code);
        }
    } else {
        tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, code);
    }

});
```

Comment: Apologies, but would you be able to reword your question? You would like the button to display `<<firstname>>?
` A simple test in console shows `console.log("<<firstname"")`
in JavaScript displays `<<firstname>>` with no problem. What is the exact code that you are using to append the text to your button or document.body? One method you may consider is using `button.textContent = "<<firstname>>` (assuming you have something such as `
let button = document.createElement("button")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed, everything between <> is being interpreted as a html tag in tinymce.
In you change the string in the `href` itself to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` it is also getting converted to `<` and `>` before it is inserted into the editor.

However you can insert `&lt;` and `&gt;` directly into the editor, and it will work as you require.

Add this function to convert the `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`:

```
function convertCode(code) {
    return String(code).replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;');
}
```

and then call it when you are inserting `code` into tinymce like this:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, convertCode(code));
```

That has worked for me before so I'm sure it will work here too.

Comment: Thanks, after including above function its working fine.

Comment: @BoopathiN Glad it worked. It's a tricky problem! I've edited your question so other people who have similar problems might find it useful too.